# find xpath element using a variable

Tags: xslt, xpath

im looking to find an element in a schema based on the value of a variable (that changes each time i iterate).  the catch is the element could be anywhere inside the schema.

for instance:

```
<...
  <foo>
    <bar>
       <bar1>BB</bar1>
       <bar2>CC</bar2>
    </bar>
    <rab>
       <rab1>DD</rab1> 
    </rab>
  </foo>
/...>
```

$attribute = bar1
(then the next iteration, $attribute may equal rab1)

how would i write an expression that could find me: `.../foo/bar/$attribute`

the closest thing i can find is `...//*[name()=$attribute]` but it doesn't work. is there any other way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your XML contain namespaces (xmlns)?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too vague. Does it throw an error? Does it return no nodes, when there are nodes it should return?

Answer (score 3):

Although the question leaves out a lot of details that may be important, you could try changing `name()` to `local-name()`:

```
...//*[local-name()='bar1']
```

and see if that fixes the problem. The return value of `name()` includes any prefix the element name has, which could cause it not to match the value of `$attribute`. (@Kirill was hinting at this.)

If that doesn't solve the problem, provide more context: What is the full XPath expression? How is it being used in XSLT? How do you know it "doesn't work"? (Give expected results and actual results.)

Comment: thanks for all your help.

when i did `//*[local-name()=string($attribute)]`

it worked

Comment: @David: I wonder if the `$attribute` variable contains something other than a string. I don't think that would make a difference, but it's hard to say, without knowing what unexpected behavior was occurring.

Comment: @David you can "accept" this answer since it solved your problem.